# Contar quantas vezes uma palavra de um arquivo aparece em outro arquivo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu gostaria de contar quantas vezes uma lista de palavras (arquivo1) aparece em outra lista de palavras (arquivo2)

```
with open("corpus.txt", "r") as f1, open("lexico.txt", "r") as f2:
    file1 = f1.read()
    file2 = f2.read()

    corpus1 = file1.split(" ")

    for word in file2:
        print(word, corpus1.count(word))
```

Arquivo corpus.txt (arquivo2)

> Tenho medo de procurar outras opções pela qualidade da luz é bastante recomendável luz muito branca, mas a duração de tudo oposta eu durou menos de meses as duas lâmpadas e que eu as colocava na luz de assistência. A luz que eu quero é mais pálida mas bastante forte para iluminar a sala.

Arquivo lexico.txt (arquivo1)

> é
>
> mas
>
> luz

Resultado

> é 2
>
> 0
>
> m 0
>
> a 2
>
> s 0
>
> 0
>
> l 0
>
> u 0
>
> z 0
>
> 0

Comment: Em lexico.txt as palavras estão separadas por "\n" (quebra de linha), sempre? Ou seja, uma palavra por linha?

Comment: Sempre separadas por uma quebra de linha! Eu tentei fazer um corpus2 = file2.split(" \n") mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Podes fazer o seguinte:

```
count = {}

with open('corpus.txt') as f1, open('lexico.txt') as f2:
    corpus = f1.read().split() # texto
    for word in f2: # palavras a quantificar no texto
        w_strp = word.strip() # retirar quebras de linha
        if w_strp != '' and w_strp not in count: # se ja a adicionamos nao vale a pena faze-lo outra vez
            count[w_strp] = corpus.count(w_strp)
print(count) # {'mas': 2, 'é': 2, 'luz': 4}
```

Ou neste caso:

```
count = {}

with open('corpus.txt') as f1, open('lexico.txt') as f2:
    corpus = f1.read().split()
    lexico = set(word.strip() for word in f2 if word.strip() != '') # set() para evitar palavras repetidas

count = {l_word: corpus.count(l_word) for l_word in lexico}
print(count) # {'mas': 2, 'é': 2, 'luz': 4}
```

Se tiveres a certeza que não palavras repetidas em `lexico.txt`, podes só:

```
...
lexico = [word.strip() for word in f2 if word.strip() != '']
...
```

Ou até:

```
count = {}

with open('temp/corpus.txt') as f1, open('temp/lexico.txt') as f2:
    corpus = f1.read().split()
    count = {l_word: corpus.count(l_word) for l_word in (word.strip() for word in f2 if word.strip() != '')}

print(count) # {'mas': 2, 'é': 2, 'luz': 4}
```

Comment: Obrigada Miguel!!! Funciona perfeitamente! Desculpe te incomodar, mas porque "not in count"? Nao deveríamos adicionar todas as entradas mesmo que repetidas para depois fazer a contagem?

Comment: @pitanga porque basta contar uma vez o número de ocorrências para cada palavra. Lembra-te que `corpus.count(w_strp)` já vai contar as ocorrências todas da primeira vez, escusamos de conta-las outra vez para a mesma palavra caso haja palavras repetidas em `lexico.txt`. Se tiveres a certeza que em `lexico.txt` não há palavras repetidas podes retirar essa condição, mantendo apenas: `if w_strp != '':`

Comment: @pitanga, reparei num bug no meu código de ontem. Falhava por exemplo quando em `corpus.txt` havia por ex: "mas é Adamastor", `{'é': 1, 'mas': 2}`, porque contava também o "mas" em "Adamastor". Acrescenta `split()` em `corpus = f1.read()`, para que se divida o corpus.txt por palavras também. Editei a resposta